# Calculate ratio row wise in a data frame

Tags: r

This is my data frame:

```
ID<-c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3))
Var1<-sample(1:100, 9, replace=TRUE)
Var2<-sample(1:100, 9, replace=TRUE)
Var3<-sample(1:100, 9, replace=TRUE)
df<-data.frame(ID, Var1, Var2, Var3)
```

I would like to apply this function column wise with

```
fun<-df[7:9 , 2]/df[4:6 ,2 ]
```

I would like to use `apply(df,2..` for each single replicate but I am not sure how this can be done.

Comment: Something like this? `apply(df[,c("Var1","Var2","Var3")],2,function(x) x[7:9]/x[4:6])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `/` is vectorized, we can do this without looping

```
df[7:9,-1]/df[4:6, -1]
#      Var1      Var2     Var3 
#7  0.57692308 1.0444444 1.888889
#8  0.08988764 0.4677419 1.548387
#9  0.61797753 2.6363636 0.281250
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to just divide rows 7:9 by rows 4:6 for each variable you could try something like this:

```
apply(df[,c("Var1","Var2","Var3")],2,function(x) x[7:9]/x[4:6])

           Var1      Var2     Var3
[1,] 0.57692308 1.0444444 1.888889
[2,] 0.08988764 0.4677419 1.548387
[3,] 0.61797753 2.6363636 0.281250
```